# How to define a type-erased ranges::view?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-erasure, std-ranges

I have a class with a predicate, for example, `Object::isValid()`. I need to iterate over only valid objects, so I'm using ranges/views:

```cpp
struct Object {
    bool isValid() const;
    // ...
};

// Usage:
std::vector<Object> objects = getObjects();
for (const auto &obj : objects |
                       std::ranges::view::filter(
                           [](const Object &obj) {
                               return obj.isValid();
                           })
    ) {
    // Use obj that is of type `const Object &`
}
```

So far so good. Now I need to separate producer and consumer of valid objects view:

```cpp
auto getValidObjectsView() {
    return objects |
           std::ranges::views::filter(
               [](const Object &obj) {
                   return obj.isValid();
               }
           );
}

void consumeValidObjects(auto &&validObjectsView) {
    for (const auto &obj : validObjectsView) {
        // Use `obj`
    }
}

consumeValidObjects(getValidObjectsView());
```

That also works, but now I need to hide the implementations of the functions into separate translation units exposing signatures in headers. Thus I cannot use `auto` anymore.

The problem is that the return type of `getValidObjectsView()` function depends on `std::ranges::views::filter` and on the lambda used inside of this function, so I cannot simply use this type in function signatures:

```cpp
using ObjectsIterable = // whatever compiler reports as decltype<getValidObjectsView()> from the previous snippet

ObjectsIterable getValidObjectsView();
void consumeValidObjects(const ObjectsIterable &)

consumeValidObjects(getValidObjectsView());
```

The question I have is how to define a proxy type `ObjectsIterable` that erases the actual underlying type of what the producer returns, something like that:

```cpp
using ObjectsIterable = std::ranges::view::one_size_fits_all_view<Object>;
```

Comment: ranges-v3 has a type erased range view called `any_view`. Standard ranges however did not do a version of this, from what I have read, because it was judged to be too un-performant to be useful. To type erase a range view you have to end up using like three separate virtual calls for each iteration or something like that -- personally i think it should be standardized and people can not use it if it is too slow for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of type erasing the returned view, you can type erase the lambda by converting it to a function pointer, which allows the function's return type to be declared as

```
std::ranges::filter_view<
    std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<Object>>, 
    bool (*)(const Object&)
>
getValidObjectsView() {
    return objects |
           std::ranges::views::filter(
               +[](const Object &obj) {
                   return obj.isValid();
               }
           );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves the main problem: the lambda in the template instantiation. Is it possible to hide the fact that the data are sourced from `std::vector`? The same for `std::ranges::filter_view`?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov For contiguous ranges like `std::vector`, you can use `std::span` for type erasure. Since there is no type-erasure view in the standard, I don't think you can erase the `ranges::xxx_view` part. The other way is to use `decltype(objects | std::views::filter(...))` to specify the return type, but you need to repeatedly spell the returned expression in `decltype`.

Comment: With current method `std::ranges::views::filter(&Object::isValid)` would also avoid lambda.

Comment: And for capturing lambda, old school (named) functor can still be used.