# How to define an internal alias of the class using the return type of its own method?

Tags: c++, alias, using, decltype

Consider the code below:

```cpp
struct LambdaWrapper {
    auto getLambda() {
        return []() {
            std::cout << "Lambda is called" << std::endl;
        };
    }
};

void useLambda(auto &&lambda) {
    lambda();
}

int main() {
    LambdaWrapper w;
    useLambda(w.getLambda());
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `auto` for both `LambdaWrapper::getLambda()` return type and for the argument of the `useLambda()` function. But actually in this code the only type is used, and that is what `LambdaWrapper::getLambda()` returns, so I can define an alias for the type:

```cpp
struct LambdaWrapper {
    auto getLambda() { ... }
    static LambdaWrapper* get();
};

using LambdaType = decltype(LambdaWrapper::get()->getLambda());
void useLambda(const LambdaType &lambda);
```

Now I wish to make this alias to be a part of the `LambdaWrapper` class:

```cpp
struct LambdaWrapper {
    auto getLambda() { ... }
    static LambdaWrapper* get();
    using LambdaType = decltype(LambdaWrapper::get()->getLambda());
};

void useLambda(const LambdaWrapper::LambdaType &lambda);
```

But now I'm getting

> error: use of ‘auto LambdaWrapper::getLambda()’ before deduction of ‘auto’

How could I define this alias inside the class?

**Update:** I still believe that my question does not need any additional details or clarity, but some responders disagree with that. So let me add more details.

My problem starts with the question here: [How to define a type-erased ranges::view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160697/how-to-define-a-type-erased-rangesview), where I'm asking how to type-erase a complex composition of range-views that use lambdas (possibly capturing), and where the type of this composition may change over time if more views would be added or changed. I see one of the solutions of that problem in the following strategy:

- Define an inline method (in the body of the class) that returns the actual complex composition of views with no type erasure.
- Let the function deduct the actual type.
- Define an alias for the return type of that method using `decltype`.
- Use that alias in any function that consumes that complex composition of views; the alias would hide that complexity, and even if the views would change, the consumer's code wouldn't.

I could do that by defining this alias as a type outside of the scope of the class. I could do that creating one more level of indirection (employing either inheritance or a nested class). But it sounds illogical that my goal cannot be achieved without hacks like inheriting from an artificial class. So the purpose of asking this question is to find the most elegant solution to implement the strategy described above.

Comment: _"only type is used"_ - I'm not seeing the actual usage. Do you need `getLambda()` to return an actual object at some point? Why not define an inner class if it gets compilcated to use a lambda in this situation?

Comment: *Now I wish to make this alias to be a part of the `LambdaWrapper` class* - you wish to use the incomplete class, this is not allowed.

Comment: If you care about the type then write a functor and work with a type name you know.

Comment: `auto getLambda() -> decltype(+[]{}) { return +[]() {...}; };`

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I realize that I can use function pointers, but this question is mostly theoretical. Considering that I have to use lambda, how could I define an inner alias?

Comment: _Why_ not make an inner class instead? That's what people usually do for functional objects that needs a proper name.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, inner class may help, thank you for the idea. Anyway, I feel that it is wrong that I cannot achieve the goal as I described. I see no reason why that cannot be achieved.

Comment: the issue is that it is syntatic sugar to have the function definition in the class body.  The `{ ... }` part isn't actually part of the class and so it is not usable while constructing the class definition.

Comment: As always, by using another level of indirection. `struct LambdaWrapperBase { ... define the lambda ... };` `struct LambdaWrapper : LambdaWrapperBase { ... define the alias ... };`

Comment: @NathanOliver, I would disagree in that it is "just syntactic sugar".

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, it would work, but sounds like a hack.

Comment: Just look at what you are trying to do: `using LambdaType = ...;` - This is just a more complicated way of writing `struct LambdaType { ... };` inside the class, and your way is a "hack" if anything.

Comment: but it is.  `struct foo { int bar() { return 42; } };` is really `struct foo { int bar(); }; int foo::bar() { return 42; }`.  That's why you can't know what the  return type is.  the function definition is after the class.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I'm using lambdas here on purpose, as this cannot be reworded with `struct LambdaType {};`

Comment: Please update the question and show the problem you are facing

Comment: @TedLyngmo, consider a more complex type like a long chain of `std::ranges::filter_view<lambda>` etc...

Comment: Sorry, I still can't "see" why an inner class can't be used.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, and I still cannot see why I would have to define an inner class to solve this problem.

Comment: The lambda is a red herring. `auto` is the real reason why you can't do what you want. `class Foo { auto bar() { ... } using baz = decltype(...bar()...); };` -- no go. Because, well, that's how C++ works. Sorry about that.

Comment: You _can_ do it as long as the lambda can be converted to a function pointer: `void(*lambda)() = []{ ... };`  and you then replace `auto` with the pointer type in your function declaration & definition - but as soon as it's capturing, nope. The type must be set before your can `decltype` it.

Comment: If you show the problem you are trying to solve instead of going down this dead end, you'll probably at least make some progress with whatever it is you want to do, even if it won't be solved using a lambda.

Comment: What is purpose of having a type for the thing no-one can construct the object for...? I mean the code is very coupled in this case.

Comment: What do you mean? Once you've done `using LambdaType = ...` it _is_ a type you can construct an object for. `LambdaType x; x();` ... Again, if the lambda is capturing, it'd be hard, because what it captures is part of its type.

Comment: Re. the added description: Please provide a minimal example with a "wanted" lambda where using a named functor type isn't feasible.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that classes are parsed in two passes. One the first pass, the compiler sees the declaration `auto getLambda()` (not a definition), and `using LambdaType = decltype(LambdaWrapper::get()->getLambda());`, however, since no definition of `getLamba` is available yet, parsing fails. This is why the compiler tells you that you are using `getLambda()` before the return type could be deduced.

If you are using C++20, the solution is trivial. You can just move the definition of your lambda into `decltype`, assuming that it has no captures:

```cpp
struct LambdaWrapper {
    using LambdaType = decltype( []() {
            std::cout << "Lambda is called" << std::endl;
    });
    LambdaType getLambda() {
        return {};
    }
};
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/j5cn3hvhK).*

A more general solution which works with older standards is to move the lambda expression into a separate scope, such as a base class:

```cpp
// note: You can also put getLambda() into a namespace, not into a class.
//       I suspect your example is overly minimal and you can't actually do that.
struct LambdaProvider {
    auto getLambda() {
        return []() {
            std::cout << "Lambda is called" << std::endl;
        };
    }
};

// At this point, LambdaProvider has been parsed completely, and we can
// obtain the type of getLambda().
struct LambdaWrapper : LambdaProvider {
    using LambdaType = decltype(std::declval<LambdaProvider>().getLambda());
};
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Mf4Gf6d7K).*

You can even turn `LambdaProvider` into a CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern) so that you can access the member functions of `LambdaWrapper` inside of it.

Comment: Unfortunately there can be captures. Moreover, that is crucial that the type is deduced from function: that is the function that defines a complex type (lambdas are just part of it).

Comment: I think general CRTP would be hard too. If capturing `this` in the lambda, the lambda can't cast `this` to `LambdaWrapper*` with the `using LambdaType = ...` inside `LambdaWrapper`.

Comment: Honestly I would need to have more details to come up with an optimal solution. OP's example is overly minimal and contains lambdas with no captures. It's unclear what problems there are with this answer considering the *actual* problem OP is trying to solve. I don't know if CRTP would work in that scenario; it's just an idea I've thrown around which may possibly work.

Comment: I totally agree and I've asked for clarification about what really needs to be done and why he can't use named functors. It'd be so simple [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Pn3YsG44T)

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov if the return type must be defined inside the function, then the function must be independent from the nesting type for the alias, inline and fully defined before the declaration of the nesting type. Otherwise you need to be able to define the type outside the function. End of discussion.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I've updated the question.