How to ensure const correctness with a vector of smart pointers in C++20?
I have inherited a large data science project in C++20. To aid reasoning through the code I started to enforce const-correctness. The project involves classes that expose vectors of smart pointers and functions that can work with read-only versions of those, i.e. with const vectors of const pointers to const objects.
Is the question of propagation solved in C++20?
How to make the marked line to compile without making extra copy of the widget vector?
I know I can solve the problem by changing the API of the class A and expose iterators rather than vectors. I would very much prefer no to change the API - enforcing const-correctness is a chore large enough, and I really don't want to task myself with adding new semantics to the code.
I cannot work without smart pointers, because there is no clear owner of Widgets in my problem domain.
I am aware of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const - it does not work with containers, and nesting it inside container like this std::vector<std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>> widgets_ does not allow for const propagation.
The closest existing question in SO: How can I propagate const when returning a std::vector<int*> from a const method?. The solution offered there does not work with smart pointers.
Using reinterpret_cast does not feel right; I've also read, that simply casting into const may cause UB.
Here's the code that illustrates my problem.
struct Widget {
   int x;
   int y;
};

class A {
public:
   A() : widgets_() { widgets_.push_back(std::make_shared<Widget>(1, 2)); }

   [[nodiscard]] std::span<const std::shared_ptr<const Widget>> getConstWidgets() const { return widgets_; } // This line does not compile.

private:
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Widget>> widgets_;
};

void do_something_with_const(std::span<const std::shared_ptr<const Widget>>);


void main() {
   A a;
   do_something_with_const(a.getConstWidgets());
}

For reference, here's a list of different but related questions:

const correctness for containers
Does span propagate const?
Turning vector of shared_ptr into vector of shared_ptr to const


More context: Can I specialize class template on constness of the type?

Unrelated: I suggest using a standard signature for main. void main() is only supported as an extension in some implementations.

@AhmedAEK Thank you for the suggestion with transform view. It is not immediately clear from the documentation: is the transform::view convertible to std::span or anything else that is agnostic to the fact that the range was transformed?

@AhmedAEK ...After some research I suppose it is impossible with std. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77160697/1261153 for a related problem with type-errasure for ranges::view.

"propagate_const - it does not work with container" It works here... It is its purpose...

@Jarod42 Yes, it does! I have simply misused it. The form you presented can be even shortened to this: https://godbolt.org/z/o5P9Mhdb3 (I hope it is still legal and no UB)

As a side question: does anyone know, why is the propagate_const "experimental"? I feel uneasy to add dependency on experimental language features on the production code.

Your shortened form is wrong std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Widget>> cannot be converted to std::vector<std::experimental::propage_const<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>>

"I feel uneasy to add dependency on experimental language features on the production code.". You can write your own, it is relatively easy to reimplement

@Jarod42 It's not a satisfying answer in my context. I cannot responsibly add into our code 100+ lines of templated C++ that to be honest, takes a non-trivial effort and time to actually understand. It would change a lot, if it was a part of the standard. The "stable", "non-experimental" standard ;-) .

The feature is experimental in that the WG21 committee responsible for the feature may make minor changes to it, may not approve it, or may start over from scratch with an entirely different approach.  Its not experimental in the sense of shoddy or janky or underdeveloped.  It experimental in the sense that it has not been committed to the standard yet.

It is the purpose of std::experimental::propagate_const and it does work Demo
If you cannot or don't want to use experimental or write your own version, you might take the problem in the other sense and change API with some kind of visitor, taking a functor working on const Widget&:
struct Widget {
   int x;
   int y;
};

class A {
public:
   A() : widgets_() { widgets_.push_back(std::make_shared<Widget>(1, 2)); }

   // template <typename F> void forEachConstWidget(F&& f) const {
   void forEachConstWidget(std::function<void(const Widget&)> f) const {
       for (const auto& p : widgets) {
           const auto& widget = *p;
           f(widget);
       }
   }

private:
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Widget>> widgets_;
};


After some thinking I concluded that it is impossible to have a C++ code that is const-correct and that even the very concept of const-correctness is not a thing that your code may have or not.
Const-correctness is a fuzzy concept, even outside C++.
What is const-correct for you, may not be const-correct for me.
The objects we pass to functions may refer to many other objects.
Constness of the immediate object is orthogonal to the constness of the objects it refers to.
That's why we distinguish const A* and A* const in C++, or const vector<int> and vector<const int>.
You may have in your code one function that adds/removes elements to/from the vector, and another that only modifies the existing elements.
Const-correctness would require you to distinguish between these two functions, and C++ allows you to mark your intentions in the argument declaration.
But that's where it ends. Let's indulge in the following case:
You have a WidgetContainer class that holds a vector of widgets of class WidgetBase, which is a virtual base class for two actual widgets: OddWidget and EvenWidget.
You have a method void doSomethingWithOddWidgets(WidgetContainer<WidgetBase> wc). How would you mark the argument in a const-correct way?
C++ does not allow you to do that, but if you fantasize with alternate language imlementations, you will conclude that the strict const-correctness will involve extra cost, because either compiler must be able to solve the impossible task to know whether your code really modifies only OddWidgets, or at least test for it in runtime.
I hope you see, where it is going: const-correctness is opinionated, best-effort concept.
Gracefully accept what the C++ already allows you to do, and abandon efforts to push it harder, as yields ever-diminishing benefits, the more correct you want it to be.
The word "correct" in the keyword "const-correctness" is misleading.
In C++, const-correctness involving myContainer<myObject> arguments is impossible, because const is more than the object's attribute set by the compiler.
The reason is that we can initialize myObject differently based on the constness of the arguments to the constructor. Widget w1{const_cast<const int>(i)} and Widget w2{const_cast<int>(i)} could have very different implementation, and therefore cannot be exchangeable objects.
Merely changing the "const" attribute on the compiler level doesn't change the object itself, and conversion without copying will cause undefined behavior.
Practical summary
We can assume duck and const duck will look and quack the same if we limit ourselves to only const methods. We cannot make such assumptions on the internal implementation, like the volume of the bone marrow. The implementer has total control over distinguishing the const and non-const ducks. If we need a duck with a const eggs in it, it is up to the duck's implementer to grant us such API. std::vectors do not allow it; all we can have is a const_iterator to the eggs, but iterator is no duck.
There exactly one exception to this rule: raw pointers.
C++ guarantees us, that the implementation of the T*const and T* are exactly the same. Therefore, C++ takes us further, and allows casting between T* and int const* (and also between int *const and int const*const). This is an exception rather than the rule: in the context of const-correctness, the type of pointee is an implementation detail, and we generally should not rely on having such vehicle for types other than raw pointers.
Even the standard smart pointers are limited here: for the const-casting pointee trick, we need to use std::experimental::propagate_const.
Should we use the ability of automatical const_cast based on the pointee type for raw pointers? That's an open question I leave unanswered.
Note, that usually we are not given the types of the objects our object refers to, so we are even not tempted. One of the reasons I started this thread was because the type of the member variable of vector is clearly visible in its type as a type's parameter. If I had seen IntVector rather than vector<int> I may have probably never even raised the problem in the first place.

I tried hard to make my answer as brief as possible. If you think I sacrificed readability, please comment.

There are 2 concepts of const in C++. The const from language, which doesn't propagate to pointer (i.e int* const allow to mutate the int). And the logical constness, where some fields can be mutated as long as object stay identical (think about cache, std::mutex) and propagation to "children" (pointer) (That one can be solved by (experimental) propagate_const).

"vector<const int>" std::vector<const T> in invalid.

"The implementer has total control over distinguishing the const and non-const ducks." limiting to const methods, there are the same, but Foo<const T> is unrelated to Foo<T>...

In a different programming language that doesn't have const, the same effect is achieved by having two different classes such as class duck and class mutable_duck : public duck.  The duck class is const by design.  The mutable_duck class derives from duck, and extends it by making it mutable.  In C++ const-correctness is similar, but it just allows both APIs to be expressed in a single class.
